# View SublimeLinter (v4) settings from SublimeText3's python console

Tags: sublimetext3, sublime-text-plugin, sublimelinter

I'm trying to view all settings for SublimeLinter so that I can update my settings file. I read [this page](https://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/reference/settings.html#file-settings) about sublime's view.settings() function, and figured it was probably in there, but the SublimeLinter documentation doesn't tell me how to access the settings from the control panel. The internal documentation is an empty string, which isn't very helpful. Any information about how to drill into plugins' settings files would be much appreciated.

Comment: The settings file is probably available in `Preferences > Package Settings > SublimeLinter`; do you have a reason you want to view them in the console instead of in a file view?

Comment: Yes - I don't think that the settings in the settings file are the "full" settings for SublimeLinter. I believe this because there are settings like "statusbar.counter_template" and "statusbar.messages_template". I would like to view and modify other properties having to do with the statusbar, but I don't know what the internal names of these settings are.

Comment: In Sublime the `settings` objects that store settings (such as you would get from `view.settings()` or `sublime.load_settings()` aren't iterable, so unless you know the setting you're looking for you can't see the value. You may have to delve into the code to see what else is there if they're not documented, or ask on the issue tracker for SL.

Comment: Thanks, I'll delve into the settings and answer my own question here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the settings, the default settings are displayed and documented on the left. There are no other settings than these. Other variable values are set internally using constants etc., there are no “secret” settings.

You can override parts of any plugin, e.g. the status bar view, if you don’t find the settings you need. Try using https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer